# Ng-click filter between 2 scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to Angular.js so I am not sure if this is the right approach. I have two scopes that are used to display 2 sets of buttons. The second set should be dependent on the button I click in the first set.

```
<!-- Insulation placement -->
  $rootScope.roofs = [
    { 
      type: 'roof',
      label: 'Pitched Roof'
    },
    { 
      type: 'attic',
      label: 'Floor of Attic' 
    }
  ];


<!-- Roof insulation types -->
  $rootScope.roofInsulation = [
    { 
      target: 'roof',
      type: 'between_rafters',
      label: 'Between Rafters'
    },
    { 
      target: 'roof',
      type: 'between_rafters_counter_batten',
      label: 'Between Rafters With A Counter Batten' 
    },
    { 
      target: 'roof',
      type: 'between_rafters_calibel',
      label: 'Between Rafters With Calibel' 
    },
    { 
      target: 'roof',
      type: 'between_rafters_thermal_laminate',
      label: 'Between Rafters With Thermal Laminate' 
    },
    { 
      target: 'attic',
      type: 'test',
      label: 'Test'
    }
  ];
```

and my HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="types in roofs">

    <button ng-click="myFilter = {target: '{{types.type}}'}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">{{types.label}}</button>

</div>

<div>

  <button ng-repeat="variants in roofInsulation | filter: myFilter" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">{{variants.label}}</button>

</div>
```

I realize that `myFilter` in the ng-click is a bit of a hack, but aside from that I can't get it to filter the results of ng-repeat. The `myFilter` variable does return the proper result `{target: 'roof'}` (for the first button). Do I assume correctly that it's because the first set of buttons is in a different scope than the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really using 2 different scopes here. If you had been using 2 different controllers or different directives then you would have got 2 different scopes. You are using $rootScope which is common across the entire angular app.

The reason `myFilter` is not working is because angular is unable to parse the expression in ng-click correctly, it's better you write a method (exposed to the scope) and change the value of `myFilter` in the method. It's a good practice as well as a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="setFilter(types)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">{{types.label}}</button>
```

**JS**

```
$rootScope.setFilter = function(types) {
    $rootScope.myFilter = {target: types.type};
}
```

Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/Lvc0u55v/10997/), I have created a working example based on your code.

**EDIT**

Even if your `target` variable is an array there shouldn't be any issue because Anguar's pipe filter will take care of it.
I have updated and created a new fiddle to show it, check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/2typnxy0/1/).

So if target is an array having 2 values - ['roof', 'attic'], that particular element will be shown for both the buttons.

Comment: One more thing that I'm wondering about. What if the "target" has multiple values. say `target: ['between_rafters', 'between_rafters_counter_batten', 'between_rafters_calibel', 'between_rafters_thermal_laminate'],` ?

Comment: Sorry, last thing :)

Comment: Is there a way to set up the filter argument from within ng-click directive? So that the function works globally, not only for the first set of buttons? Example: 
`$rootScope.setFilter = function( $somearg ) {
    $rootScope.myFilter = {target: $somearg.type};
} `
And 
`<button ng-click="setFilter(($somearg = types))" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">{{types.label}}</button>`
Something like that?

Comment: @PawełDurczok, both your queries are possible. For the first one I have edited the function and for your send query, it is possible as long as the 'myFilter' function is accessible to the button. So if you declare your myFilter function in the global level, you can easily achieve it.

Comment: @PawełDurczok, please mark or upvote the answer it has helped you

Comment: Already have, but since my reputation was low it didn't show up.

Comment: @PawełDurczok, for marking a answer you don't need reputation, it's needed only for Upvoting. However I upvoted your question, so you should be having enough reputation. :-)

Comment: No Problem, Thanks